# How can I terminate

Tags: python, sockets

I am learning socket programming and python.  For a school assignment, I created a server that runs, but I don't know how to terminate it.  The instruction says that my server runs repeatedly until terminated by a supervisor (don't lead open sockets).  Can someone give me an example or point me to the right direction? Thanks so much!

Here is a portion of my code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os

def main():
    #HOST = ''
    #PORT = 8888

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print 'Socket created'

    try:
        server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))    #bind to a address(and port)
    except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()

    print 'Socket bind complete'

    #put the socket in listening mode
    server_socket.listen(10)     #maximum 10 connections
    print 'TCP Server Waiting for client on port 30021'

    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    client, addr = server_socket.accept()
    #display client information
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    try:
        #keep talking with the client
        while 1:
            #Receiving from client
            data = client.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break

            #DO SOMETHING HERE

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Exiting gracefully."
    finally:
        server_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How you terminte a program depends in part upon how you started it. How did you start this program?

Comment: Is terminating it with `KeyboardInterrupt` not sufficient?

Comment: Send `''` to the server, that will close the connection, and with this piece of code, that will terminate the program.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running it interactively (that is, you started it with e.g. `python myprogram.py` or `./myprogram.py` and you have a console where you can see its output), you should be able to send it an interrupt, by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. You should then see the “exiting gracefully” message and it should terminate.

If you're running it some other way, how to terminate it depends on what platform you're using. If you're on Windows, you should be able to find the `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe` process and press <kbd>End Process</kbd> in Task Manager. If you're on a POSIX system, you might be able to find the process with `ps` and end it with `kill -INT id`, where `id` is the process ID you obtained from `ps`.